How to read s3 data using AWS Athena
I am just doing one POC
where I am trying to read data using AWS Athena from AWS , Procedure I am following is below
1- Adding  CSV Files in AWS S3

2-Creating Glue Crawler and Create AWS Glue Database while giving all permission for IAM role ,adding classifier for CSV data
3- Running that Crawler
4-Going to Athena checking DBs and Tables all are there but the data is not visible this is the problem I am facing

How can I see the data ??
I want to see data values there but I am only able to see column names
Note -I am doing this in Single AWS account

You would normally need to have a separate directory for each table, with the relevant data file(s) in that directory. So we can help diagnose your situation, please click the 3 dots next to a table name and select Generate table DDL, then Edit your Question and show us the DDL that was generated.

can you also share a screenshot of how the data in the files look like? When using crawlers with csv files, the format of how you save the files is important if you dont want to use custom classifiers. Other option is to save the files as parquet.

As a test I would create subfolders for each of the files in that S3 location and move the files to the appropriate subfolder and then run the crawler again.
